# Should I learn to use RPN

Tags: calculator

I'm a young scientific student in high school (Lycée français). And I wanted to know if RPN would be interesting at my level?  I do possess a RPN calculator (HP Prime),  so I can start to use it anytime.

Thanks

Comment: I think this is an opinion question and not suited for this forum.  Having said that, RPN is a preference.  If you intend to study computer science then I would _strongly_ recommend learning RPN.  Otherwise, RPN is simply a preference.  I tend to think in terms of RPN--and that's because I learned it in high school.  RPN will help you understand order of operations better and that the various elementary operations are actually functions.  But I cannot say for certain, in your circumstance, whether or not RPN is right for you.

Comment: To my experience, one can get pretty far in pure math (PhD, for example) without knowing reverse polish notation.

Comment: @Roland Really???  You have a PhD in mathematics and don't think knowing about [Backus-Naur Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) is important?  I say that because someone vaguely familiar with formal languages is _bound_ to know the difference between post-fix (RPN), pre-fix, and in-fix (what we normally see expressions as).

Comment: @Jared we could continue this conversation in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics

Comment: @Jared Is it that useful with computer calculations? I'm curious about it!

Comment: @Jared: Mathematics is a very large field, and there is no reason to expect someone with a PhD in mathematics to be familiar with formal languages.

Comment: @user29634: As far as calculators are concerned, the choice between RPN and traditional parenthesis notation is, as **Jared** said, a matter of taste. I find RPN a far more natural way to enter compound calculations into an ordinary calculator, but I’ve known people who made considerable use of calculators and very much disliked it. Since you have an RPN calculator, you can try it out and see whether you like it or not. If you do, be sure to give it some time for the initial unfamiliarity to wear off.

Comment: I'm going to try it!  For now,  it looks really cool to use?

Comment: @user29634 The reason it's important in computer science is because you will learn about things like [abstract syntax trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).  Knowing RPN is a first step in understanding how to parse a statement in a computer programming language.  Most languages are written in "in-fix" form which tend to be ambiguous and require precedence definitions (that goes back to BNF).  RPN is a completely unambiguous way of writing an expression and the idea is how to we take in-fix (ambiguous) and translate it to a very concrete, non-ambiguous, form like RPN.

Comment: @Jared Thanks! I understand why now. Since two days,  I'm using my calculator with RPN turned on ;)